# Synch clocks between client and server in Java

Tags: java, networking, client-server, synchronization

We're developing a simple boggle game in Java for a college project (purely academic purposes, so we're trying to keep it simple).

Our application is composed by a client portion and a server portion. The idea is that when a game starts all the participants have a fixed amount of time (3 minutes) to find words from the grid.

Of course we have to ensure that all timers start at the same time and players with higher ping don't get penalized. By searching on Google and other forums most people suggest the correct approach is to implement the (S)NTP algorithm, even though for a similar question [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/201756/how-to-sync-clocks-over-networking-for-game-development) someone suggested that NTP is overkill. Is it or is it not?

Our idea is basically this: when the game starts, the server sends to all the participants a future datetime to start the timer task and then simply waits for the clients to communicate the results. If indeed NTP is the best approach I'd like to know if there are alternatives to the already available Apache Commons Net library since we're using Java 14 with modules and JavaFX, so we need to use jlink and it doesn't allow for non-modular dependencies. Thanks in advance